# Dynamic pointStart in HighCharts ( RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, highcharts

My application takes two dates from a user via jQuery Datepicker with a specified time. How can I pass this into my HighCharts javascript as the pointStart attribute?
I store the start date in the controller as:

```
@start = :time.chop+":00"
```

The resulting format is:

```
"2011-12-06 12:00:00"
```

In my highcharts series section I use the following which displays the data correctly but uses the default date of Jan 1, 1970. The commented line also fails:

```
series: [{
    pointInterval: <%= 30.minute %>,
    pointStart: <%= @start %>,
    //pointStart: <%= @start.to_date %>,
    data: <%= @data %>
}]
```

Am I using the correct date format, or is the only option to convert the date to milliseconds? I know it is something small I'm missing but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, highcharts (well really JavaScript) needs you to convert to milliseconds.  So if @start is a Time object:

```
pointStart: <%= @start.to_i * 1000 %>,
```

Comment: Thanks a mil, that's exactly what I was missing